# How to encrypt WS-Addressing headers

Tags: wcf, webservice-client, ws-security

Scenario: I am writing a WCF client to access a Java/Metro webservice which requires several SOAP headers to be signed and encrypted:

```
<wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
      <sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:Body/>
        <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        <sp:Header Namespace="... application specific headers ..."/>
      </sp:SignedParts>
      <sp:EncryptedParts>
        <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        <sp:Header Namespace="... application specific headers ..."/>
      </sp:EncryptedParts>
    </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

It works for the application specific headers (the ProtectionLevel attribute is applied on the respective proxy type members). The WS-Addressing headers, however, are **signed but not encrypted**.

I tried to add them programmatically to the `ChannelProtectionRequirements` message parts collection(s) through contract or endpoint behaviors (e.g. like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/01/18/securing-custom-headers-version-1.aspx)). No success.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is very strange requirement. Not encrypting WS-Addressing has its purpose. It is like sending letter and putting destination address inside instead of writting it on envelope so only recipient can open and read it but without knowing destination address you can't deliver it to recipient.

Comment: Granted, if it actually makes sense to encrypt WS-Addressing headers may be debatable. However, I can imagine scenarios where some headers like e.g. ReplyTo, From, maybe even RelatesTo might carry information that you'd want to hide from prying eyes. Consider (logical) direct communication -- thus, no need for intermediary processors -- without transport level security (think HTTP).

Anyway, I know that it is possible with Java's Metro framework and I need clear evidence whether or not this can be done with WCF...

Comment: Apart from exact answers to that questions, some pointers to in-depth material on WCF & WS-SecurityPolicy 1.2 might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sackcloth & ashes coming up. I'm not sure what went wrong in my tests, but it **does** work when I add the respective headers to the IncomingSignatureParts and IncomingEncryptionParts of the service endpoint through a contract behavior.